# How do I upgrade to ember-cli 3.17.0?

Tags: npm, npm-install, ember-cli

I am currently upgrading my web project to Ember `3.17.0`. While `ember` and `ember-data` are showing `3.17.0` in the web browser console window, ember-cli is stuck at `3.16.1` when I run `ember --version`

**Upgrade steps:**

`npm uninstall -g ember-cli`

`npm install -g ember-cli@3.17.0`

Am I doing something wrong or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to update ember-cli is with [ember-cli-update](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-update)

```sh
cd YOUR_APP_DIRECTORY
npx ember-cli-update
```

That will not only update the version of ember-cli in your package.json, it will also make any other changes to the blueprints that come with a new ember app ensuring you have the latest and greatest options for building and running your ember.

Comment: With respect to making changes to the blueprints, does that happen automatically? Where does `ember-cli-update --run-codemods` come into place?

Comment: The blueprint updates happen automatically so you'll want to follow the recommendations in that link to ensure your project is under version control and then review the changed. I find that I apply around 90% of them each time I update. You can get an idea about what qualifies as a blueprint by taking a look at the output of a [brand new app](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-new-output)

Running codemods is a different step which you can do after updating. It's going to change your application code as opposed to the default config stuff that ember ships.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I needed to run `npm install` after running `npm install -g ember-cli@3.17.0`. I figured this out by running `ncu -u` and it caught the fact that `ember-cli` needed to updated and it told me to run `npm install`.

Note: For those who do not know what `ncu` is, it is `npm-check-updates`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates